# Sequelize use same transaction from within multiple files

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, transactions, sequelize.js

I have a NodeJs controller file, with the logic to update a row of a table(suppose T1) using Sequelize in MySQL DB. I also have the Sequelize model file for T1 where I am using the afterupdate hook to check if a particular column of T1-instance was updated or not and then based on that update a row in another table( suppose T2). Because of this check, I cannot keep both updates in the same controller file. But the problem is that I want both of the update operations to be a part of the same transaction. And I am unable to do it, because, the update operations are coded in 2 separate files in 2 separate methods. I am not able to figure out how to declare the transaction in a common helper file and try to use it separately from the model file and controller file. Kindly help with suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass the current transaction to all queries then you need to use `CLS`, see [Automatically pass transaction to all queries](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#automatically-pass-transactions-to-all-queries)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Anatoly. But I don't want to use the same transaction for all the queries. Different APIs in my tool is supposed to run different set of queries. And, for each set with multiple update queries I need a different transaction.

Comment: Did you look at https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#with-cls-enabled ?